# Concatenation of two strings in java with only first character in upper case

Tags: java, string

I am trying to get two string firstName and lastName which is fully in uppercase and tring to convert all the characters except  the first one in lowercase and concatenate the resultant strings.

firstname="TOM";
lastName="HARRIS";

Output is : Tom Harris

I achieved it by doing:

```
String name =
  firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
  + firstName.substring(1).toLowerCase()
  + " "
  + lastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
  + lastName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

but is there any other way of doing ? a more efficient way ?

Comment: Why convert the first character to uppercase when it is already uppercase, according to your description? Not doing that would remove two `String` constructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the method `WordUtils.capitalizeFully()` from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/index.html):

```
String name = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(firstName + " " + lastName);
```

Comment: The requirement is not to capitalize all.

Comment: WordUtils.capitalizeFully is defined as _"Converts all the whitespace separated words in a String into capitalized words, that is each word is made up of a titlecase character and then a series of lowercase characters."_ So this does meet the requirements.

Comment: I would like to convert all characters but my first to lowercase

Comment: @Rakesh, yes this does what you need. Read Manuzor's comment, hmjd is mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

As Strings are immutable in Java, when doing that many concatenations it's more efficient to use a StringBuilder, like so:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
String name = s.append(firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase())
              .append(firstName.substring(1).toLowerCase())
              .append(" ")
              .append(lastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase())
              .append(lastName.substring(1).toLowerCase()).toString();
```

As this only creates 2 objects: the String and the StringBuilder, rather than 4* as before.

*Concatenating a String literal is done at compile time, so adding the `" "` does not create a new object.

Comment: That's not exactly true. From Java 1.5 the compiler optimizes "+" operator using a StringBuilder. http://caprazzi.net/posts/java-bytecode-string-concatenation-and-stringbuilder/

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I've been living a lie for months!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a little more control in building up Strings [Snippetory](http://www.jproggy.org/snippetory/) may help

```
Syntaxes.XML_ALIKE.parse("{v:x case='camelizeUpper' delimiter=' '}").append("x", firstName).append("x", lastName).toString();
```